# How to start RDS database instance using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cmd, aws-cli

A have a DB instance on AWS RDS.

I have a windows cmd script supposed to start a db instance. Once it's started, it should continue some other operations.

```
    aws rds start-db-instance --db-instance-identifier SomeDatabase
    aws rds wait db-instance-available --db-instance-identifier SomeDatabase
    aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    aws ec2 wait instance-running --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The first line of the script works and starts the database. However it writes a long Json description of the instance. The json description is so long that I have to manually press enter until the entire json is printed to the screen before continuing other operations.

Does anyone know how to start an instance without printing the descriptive json or without any manually required intervention ?

Thanks.
Cheers,

Comment: Depends on your OS and shell. Is it linux and bash? Windows?

Comment: @Marcin it's windows cmd script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--no-cli-pager` in your commands. This will prevent the default behaviour of paginating output.

You can remove this behaviour by default by setting this configuration:

```
[default]
cli_pager=
```

See: [Using AWS CLI pagination options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html)

Alternatively, you could specify the output you want rather than the default "show all" by using the `--query` parameter.

Comment: Wow, that's wild that this is the default behavior!

Comment: Yes, they changed the default with CLI v2. It reduces the number of back-end calls to AWS and gives the first result set faster, so they considered it better behaviour. Personally, I just did the above and reset it to the "show all" behaviour.